# A Duplicate name exists on the network

Tags: windows-server-2008

Recently we changed out office IT structure from having a dedicated server to be the DC, a dedicated server for the exchange etc... (Each running Windows Server 2003 R2)

Now we have a single server running Windows SBS 2008 and created a new domain (with a different domain name) We then changed every PC so it connected to the new domain and renamed every PC with a new naming structure.

After I had done this, we were getting several PCs that would get the following message just before the login screen (Alt+Ctrl+Del Screen)

> A Duplicate name exists on the network

I have checked the ADUC and have removed the trouble PCs from the list and renamed each PC and changed the SID before connecting back onto the domain but still getting this message.

I have tried everything that i can think of but still getting the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreticated.

Comment: Have you checked DNS for stale/invalid A records?

Comment: Yes. There are only a few PCs listed and these ones are not causing a problem. I have just tried to add new records to DNS for the troubled machines and removed the pc from the domain and then but it back on and the issue is still the same.

Comment: Are you sure all machines on the new domain have different names (FQDN, lmhost, WINS, netbios, etc...) and SID? Also, is the new DNS setup (on the server) built from scratch or a duplication? Something is confusing old data with components of the new domain.

Comment: If you're running WINS I suggest you purge all entries and let it rebuild, as that is a common cause of this problem, especially when there's a lot of renaming going on.

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure all machines on the new domain have different names (FQDN, lmhost, WINS, netbios, etc...) and SID? Also, is the new DNS setup (on the server) built from scratch or a duplication? Something is confusing old data with components of the new domain.